# Windows Live Mail Error ID: 0x80048849

Tags: windows-7, hotmail, windows-live-mail

I'm using Windows Live Mail as my mail client on windows.

It recently stopped working with my hotmail account, it says it can't send or receive email.

It does work with Gmail, which is odd.

I tried searching for a solution, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control Panel → Internet Options → Advanced
2. Click both [restore settings] buttons that you see on that page (restore advanved and restore)
3. Close IE or Windows Live Mail (if open)
4. Open windows live email and... voila!

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a few clean installs of Win7, LiveMail always gave me trouble.

re:   Windows Live Mail Error ID: 0x80048849

1. Clean install
2. Vipre Antivirus 4.0.3904 set in learning mode.
3. Installed LiveMail...added my hotmail account and just let LiveMail do the setup.

Vipre learning mode set WLIDSVC.EXE and wlmail.exe in the application exceptions.

getting the above error still

Turned off Vipre "Web Filtering"

getting the above error still

Vipre Web Filtering also has an "Allowed Application" tab at this point I added WLIDSVC.EXE and WLIDSVCM.EXE as exceptions and now LiveMail works without a problem.

Just to make a note... wlmail.exe, wlcomm.exe were put as exceptions prior to... but failed

When WLIDSVC.EXE, and WLIDSVCM.EXE were added to the web filtering/allowed apps tab and the web filtering re-enabled

All works good

It seems that in my case at least it was something with the firewall stopping something

....Hope the helps

Comment: Just another note... when vipre was turned off and I still got the error...

Answer (score 0):

Just restore advance settings and below there is reset internet explorer settings click on it.
Everything in live mail will be ok.